# Hibernate cache not working with RichFaces bean

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, caching, richfaces

I'm having a bean that basically calls `getSession().createCriteria(ObjClass.class).list();` each time a request is made. It takes 16 secs to load everything first time, then it takes like 1 or so. Thing is that in a unit test cache works great, but when multiple requests are made to a bean, it never even uses cache. Question is why?

Info: it's a second level hibernate (3.5.x) cache (2.0) with `org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider` and query level cache usage turned on. Using richfaces 3.3.3 request scoped bean with keep alive enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't make the query cachable, it won't be cached:

```
getSession().createCriteria(ObjClass.class)
            .setCacheable(true)
            .list();
```

You could also set the cache region for more fine-grained configuration.

Comment: I don't make query cachable in tests and tests use same DAO as bean does.

Comment: Didn't help, it took 16 secs before, now it takes 17 first time and reduces down to 16.

Comment: Is the ObjClass class cacheable? Have you looked at the generated SQL queries?